# Algorithm to read in a column from a text file in c

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, fopen

Here is my current code:

```
void NormRead(Normal *norm1) {
    FILE *normfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\NormData.txt", "r");

    double NormArray[250]= {0};

    if (normfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not open file.\n");
        exit(99);
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<250 ; ++i) {

        if(feof(normfile)) {
            break;
        }

        fscanf(normfile, "%lg", &NormArray[i]);
    }

    printf("%lg", NormArray[0]);

    fclose(normfile);
}
```

Honestly, I can't see why this won't work, `NormArray` is unchanged by my `for()` loop, if I print the whole thing afterward it's all zeros still.
The data file I'm reading from is just a 1 column file like so:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

The actual values are different but that shouldn't matter.

Any help? I feel this should be done to death on the internet, but I couldn't find anything to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_if I print the whole thing afterward it's all zeros still._" --> How are you printing? In your function `NormRead()`, you are just printing the `0th` element of the array in which you have read the file contents.

Comment: A [mcve] please!

Comment: Notice that you're not doing anything with `norm1`

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense from many, many different perspectives. First:

```
void NormRead(Normal *norm1)
```

You are passing `Normal *norm1` as a parameter but it is never used in your function??

Do not hardcode filenames in your code.

```
    FILE *normfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\NormData.txt", "r");
```

If you need a *filename* in your function - pass a `char *filename` as a parameter. If you need constants, (such as a *default filename*), declare them at the top of the sourcefile. That way you never end up picking though your source to adjust a constant, they are all defined in a simple convenient location, not sprinkled and buried in functions throughout your code.

There is no need for an array if you are simply outputting each of the first `250` values you read from a file. Simply print the values.

**important side-note about array declarations within a function**

Further (even though you make no attempt to) you cannot return a pointer to an array with automatic storage declared locally within a function The storage for the array exists within memory provided for the function (the function stack frame) and is destroyed (released for re-use) as soon as the function returns. (and any attempt to access memory that has been released is *Undefined Behavior*).

Your only options in the event you want to fill the array in your function and make the values available back in the caller are (1) to pass an array with sufficient storage as a parameter to your function to fill or (2) dynamically allocate memory within your function and return a pointer to the newly allocated block which survives the function return. (or actually 3 - pass the *address of* a valid pointer as a parameter and allocate (or reallocate) and fill within your function)

**continuing**

If you are limiting the values you print to `250`, don't hardcode *magic numbers* in your code. Either declare a constant as mentioned above, or pass the limit as a parameter to your function. You can define both constants with a simple `#define`, e.g.

```
#define READMAX 250
#define FNDEFAULT "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\NormData.txt"
```

You do validate that `normfile` is open, but you use `exit(99);`. The C library provides for two `exit` conditions and provides the constants `EXIT_SUCCESS (0)` and `EXIT_FAILURE (1)`. They are defined in `stdlib.h`. It is recommended you use what the library provides rather than *hard-coding more magic numbers* in your code.

Your read loop is *awkward* (at best). If you are limiting your read to `250` values then a more proper way to do it would simply be:

```
    int n = 0;
    double tmp;
    ...
    /* read up to READMAX double values from filename */
    while (n < READMAX && fscanf (normfile, "%lg", &tmp) == 1) {
        printf (" %g", tmp);
        n++;
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
```

You will only ever print one value printing with:

```
    printf("%lg", NormArray[0]);
```

(you simply print the first value read `NormArray[0]` over-and-over again. **Zero** really means **zero**. Further `"%lg"` in an improper *format specifier* as `"%g"` expects a `double` by default (unlike the `scanf` functions))

Putting it altogether, what it appears you are attempting to do can be boiled down to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define READMAX 250
#define FNDEFAULT "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\NormData.txt"

void NormRead (char *filename) 
{
    int n = 0;
    double tmp;
    FILE *normfile = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (!normfile) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", filename);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    /* defined in stdlib.h */
    }

    /* read up to READMAX double values from filename */
    while (n < READMAX && fscanf (normfile, "%lg", &tmp) == 1) {
        printf (" %g", tmp);
        n++;
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    fclose (normfile);  /* close file */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    /* set fn to 1st argument (or FNDEFAULT if none given) */
    char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FNDEFAULT;

    NormRead (fn);  /* call NormRead function */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/normread.txt
1

2

3

4

5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/normread dat/normread.txt
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Look things over and let me know if I interpreted what you were attempting to do correctly. If you actually intended to make use of the array somehow, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

There are no of bugs in your program like

```
for (int i=0 ; i<250 ; ++i) {
```

Why rotate loop 250 times, make it generic, rotate loop until `EOF` occurs. Don't use `feof()`, usage of `feof()` is discourages.

Modify your `fscanf()` part as

```
for ( i=0 ;  ; ++i) {

                if((fscanf(normfile, "%lg", &NormArray[i]))<0) {
                        break;
                }
        }
```

When there is no further data in file, `fscanf()` returns `-1` and that time `i` is nothing but `no of values in the file`, while printing columns, rotate loop `i` times .

Instead of printing only NormArray[0], try to print all as

```
for( j=0 ;j<i ; ++j)//  here i is the total no input in file
        printf("%lg\n", NormArray[j]);
```

I can't assume what your doing with `Norm1` in the function `NormRead()`

I Hope it will helps.